# Compare date range to array values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, concatenation

I'm trying to create a function to concatenate a range of cells, IF their respective dates are Bigger or Equal ( >= ) to a specific date stored in a cell on the sheet.

In the code below, `DatesRange_V` is an array with a list of dates, and `ThisDate` is A1 containing a date. I wish to Loop through `ConcatRange_V` and concatenate them with a separator when the dates are bigger than `ThisDay`.

```
Function ConcatRangeIf() As String
Dim ConcatRange As Range
Dim DatesRange As Range

Set ConcatRange = Range("RP_Names")  'A list of names to concat
Set DatesRange = Range("RP_Dates")  'A list of dates

Dim Result As String
Dim Seperator As String
Dim FirstCell As Boolean

Dim ConcatRange_V() As Variant
Dim DatesRange_V() As Variant
Dim ThisDate As Variant

FirstCell = True
Seperator = ", "

ConcatRange_V = ConcatRange.Value
DatesRange_V = DatesRange.Value
ThisDate = Range("a1").Value ' A date on the current sheet

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(ConcatRange_V)
    If ConcatRange_V(i, 1) <> "" And DatesRange_V(i, 0) >= ThisDate Then
        If FirstCell Then
            Result = ConcatRange_V(i, 1)
        Else
            Result = Result & Seperator & ConcatRange_V(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
FirstCell = False
Next

ConcatRangeIf = Result
End Function
```

There seems to be a problem, as the cell I have placed `=ConcatRangeif()` is returning `#VALUE!`.

Answer (score 1):

if this is trully a copy of your code then the line:

```
ConcatRange_V = ConcatR.Value
```

ConcatR points to a variable that has not been assigned a value.  It should read:

```
ConcatRange_V = ConcatRange.Value
```

Comment: Well spotted. It went through a renaming process but this is not the issue. Will update the code in the question.